# iTunesConnect - If I don't submit 5.8" display screenshots, will my 5.5" screenshots be displayed instead for people using the iPhone X?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm about to submit my app on iTunesConnect, but I see that there's now the option to submit screenshots for the iPhone X. I know that they're optional, but if I don't submit them, and just submit the regular 5.5" screeenshots, will those be displayed on the app store, or will nothing be displayed for people using the iPhone X?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 5.5" screenshots will be displayed on the App Store for iPhone X users.

Comment: Is this still valid? Because now 6,5-inch are marked as optional, but 5,8 do not have "optional" mention